# How to change the View of UITableViewCell on selection

Tags: iphone

I want to change the color of label text on selection and get back the previus color on deselection.  If you have solution please tell me. Looking for good response as earlier :-)

Comment: You should really accept some answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the label's `highlightedTextColor` accordingly.

Comment: Hi Ole, i wrote this statement but its not working.Please tell me where I am wrong                                             lblTitle.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor redColor];

Comment: Thanks Dude, Its working perfectly now. I was wrong earlier :-)